# sql favourite drink in cafe

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to show list of favourite drink from each member, but I am really confused how to do it. The image below will show all the information needed for the new query, I only need to show member id and favourite drink. Favorite drink is determined from the quantity.

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want an SQL Server (TSQL) query or something for ms-access?

Comment: What's the expected result? (And if a user has two drifferent favorite drinks?)

Comment: from microsoft access.

Comment: show 2 favorite drinks

Comment: First things first, you need to decide how you're going to determine which products are drinks and which ones aren't.

Comment: sorry what i mean is food or drinks for example memberM01001 have 2 favorites which is smoked salmon sandwich and Apple juice

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to do it with a TSQL query. This should be possible to query in MS Access too i think. Otherwise it should help you on the way:

```
SELECT a.MemberID, b.ProductName 
FROM 
    (SELECT MemberID, MAX(quantity) AS quantity 
    FROM <your table> 
    GROUP BY MemberID
    --WHERE <product type column> = 'drink product type'
    ) a
INNER JOIN <your table> b ON a.MemberID = b.MemberID AND a.quantity = b.quantity --AND b.<product type column> = 'drink product type'
```

**Edit:** In this answer, I took for granted that all products were drinks. Howvever,  as i saw Rich Benner's comment below the question I realized that there are sandwiches and salads in the ProductName-column. As mentioned, you need a product type column in your table to be able to distinguish them from each other. Then you need to add a conditions in both of your selects (see commented sections in query), filtering it on the desired product type.

Comment: thank you for your answer ,but what should a and b means? i extract information from query(Favorite)

Comment: 'a' and 'b' are just aliases for the tables we're using in the query. Their names are just nonsense since I'm lazy. You should name them something that makes more sense.

So this is a result from a query? Can you show us the original tables? can you show us your query?